# conditional simple/comple types in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I would like to create Schema Definition for the following xml:

price node may have simple numerical value:

```
<price>1000000</price>
```

or price node may have **one and only** child `daily`:

```
<price>
  <daily>500</daily>
</price>
```

or price node may have **one and only** child `weekly`:

```
<price>
  <weekly>4000</>weekly> 
</price>
```

Is it possible ? If so, how to define `price` element using XSD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD, you cannot allow both simple and complex content unless you're willing to have mix elements and text via `mixed="true"`.  You *could* then used XSD 1.1 assertions to exclude both from appearing simultaneously.

However, you're swimming upstream here.  Instead, change your XML design to make the information conveyed by `daily` vs `weekly` be an attribute rather than an element:

```
<price> 1000000 </price>
<price frequency="daily">500</price>
<price frequency="weekly">4000</price>
```

Then you'll have no problem defining an XSD for `price`.